# Alternate JUnit textui TestRunner

Tags: java, groovy, junit

I'm writing some system tests in Groovy and piggybacking on its unit testing infrastructure. It works pretty well except that I don't like the default JUnit test runner, which displays . for each test in the suite waiting until the end to report details about the errors and failures. The system tests can take a long time to run so it's useful to be able to interrupt them in the middle once you know that a failure or error exists but you can only do that if you know which testcase failed and what the failure was while the suite is running.

Are there any alternate JUnit test runners which I could use that provide this functionality out of the box?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what you mean by "textui", but [IntelliJ IDEA 11 Community Edition](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download/index.html) has an integrated JUnit test runner that works with Groovy exactly as you describe (but it has a graphical user interface only, as far as I know).

Comment: It's a package in JUnit. I need a text interface that's not the default one provided by JUnit.